# Switching between two background color with one button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, background

I have a problem with my website. I would like to cycle in two different backgrund colors with one button (from white to black and from black to white) Another thing which I want to is to change font color with the same button (from black to white and from white to black. The reason why I want this is that I want to make negative version of my website with a button click. Can somebody post me the script and the button html tag?

The background color and the font color is defined with these tags in CSS:

body {color: $(body.text.color); background: $(body.background);}

So the script should change this values, I thing.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create css classes:

```
#target {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

.negative {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Then execute this on click:

```
$('#target').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('negative');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQ8bR/)

Comment: or with plain javascript:  `document.body.classList.toggle("negative");` http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/pQ8bR/1/

Comment: @NicoO nice note, but unfortunately browser support is weak yet for that method: http://caniuse.com/classlist

Comment: Good catch @karaxuna I did not know it was IE10+.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I cant see there the button definition or something like that. I mean there is script but where is defined where to click to execute it, where is the button? You know? Althought thanks very much.

Comment: @user3473897 in fiddle example click event is bound to `body` tag. There is no problem to modify this code to feet your needs